# how to add dynamic data to morris bar chart

Tags: jquery, ajax, morris.js

I want to add data to Morris bar-chart via ajax. Following is the json which i get in ajax success

`[{"x":"2014-10-02","y":"1"},{"x":"2014-10-19","y":"1"},{"x":"2014-10-20","y":"1"},{"x":"2014-11-13","y":"1"}]`

following is the js code

```
var chart = Morris.Bar({
        element : 'normal-bar-graph',
        data : [{
            "x" : null,
            "y" : null
        }],
        xkey : 'x',
        ykeys : ['y'],
        labels : ['Added']
    });
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "some_url",
            data: {'user_report':[k,v]},

            success: function(html)                    
            {   
                if(html == "error")
                {
                alert('error');
                }
                else
                {
                    chart.setData(html);

                }
                hide_loading();
            }
        });
```

am using `/morris/raphael.2.1.0.min.js` and `/morris/morris.min.js`.
 The `chart.setData(html);` functionality does not work as said in the documentation of morris.

thank in advance. please point me out if any error made.

have also made a jsbin if that can help: [morris](http://jsbin.com/nepavododu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes. `setData` expects an array. When you use quotes, it converts that into a string instead of array.

Like this : `chart.setData([{ "y": "2006", "a": 100, "b": 90 },{ "y": "2006", "a": 100, "b": 90 }]);`

Comment: But it shows only one graph. Also when i want to get data via ajax,  `chart.setData()`.

Comment: @dhpratik: What do you mean by "*it shows only one graph*"? The solution provided above should work or else, you're not telling us the whole picture.

Comment: Yeah. Looks like that was because of a bug - https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/105
Update your scripts to latest version of morris bar graph and everything works.  http://jsbin.com/kiduwuseda/edit?html,js,output . But my original solution _is_ the fix to your question.

Comment: i have given the jsbin link above, when i put in json array in `setData` it shows me graph of only the last data from the json string. also my main consern was how will i put in json array  stored in an variable (as mainly asked in my question)

Comment: thanks, working fine in the jsbin. hope it also works fine via my ajax call to fetch data.